# Celery Error Handling

Tags: error-handling, python-3.6, celery-task

I've built a fairly simple application linking Flask, Celery, and RabbitMQ using docker-compose by linking together a few solutions I saw online. I'm having some issues trying to update task states to reflect if a failure occurred. To keep error visibility at it's highest, I've had my custom class only raise expected errors, else the errors are handled at the celery app level as follows (in `celery_app.py`):

```
@celery_app.task(name='celery_worker.summary')
def async_summary(data):
    """Background summary processing"""
    try:
        logger.info('Summarizing text')
        return BdsSummary(data, nlp=en_nlp).create_summary()
    except Exception as e:
        current_task.update_state(state='FAILURE', meta={'error_message': str(traceback.format_exc())})
        logger.exception('Text Summary worker raised: %r'%e)
```

I've been doing some negative testing against my application, and when I pass it data that I know will throw an error (non-text data, for example), when i run `r = requests.get('http://my.app.addr:8888/task/my-task-id')` I get `{'status': 'SUCCESS', 'result': None}`. I'm vexed as to why this is happening. Based on my admittedly limited understanding of Celery's behavior, it should update the status to show a traceback and `ExceptionClass`, why would it not do this?

I am relatively new to Celery, so my understanding of the Canvas that they reference in the documentation is extremely basic. I'm just trying to provide some basic task failure information to the response/task. For context, when I give it proper input, I get back `{'status': 'SUCCESS', 'result': {'summary': 'My Summary text here', 'num_sentences': 3, ...}}`.

Any insight here would be much appreciated

Comment: I may have figured out part of the problem. Since I'm handling the exception, the state is updated to `FAILURE`. However, in the time between the update and me polling the task, the worker is able to finish the task definition. That sets the response to `SUCCESSFUL` state and it returns `NoneType`. I'm going to see if there is a way for me to utilize Celery's packages to have the final update be `FAILED` with a stacktrace. Maybe retry...